# How to properly type hint a class decorator?

Tags: type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-3.9, python-3.10

Assume we have some function `func` that maps instances of class `A` to instances of class `B`, i.e. it has the signature `Callable[[A], B]`.

I want to write a class decorator `autofunc` for subclasses of `A` that automatically applies `func` to instances as they are created. For example, think of automatic jit-compilation based on a global environment variable. This can be done via

```py
from functools import wraps

def autofunc(basecls):
    @wraps(basecls, updated=())

    class WrappedClass(basecls):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = basecls(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(instance)
    return WrappedClass
```

Then the following two are roughly equivalent:

| `class C(A):` `...` `instance = func(C())` | `@autofunc` `class C(A):` `...` `instance = C()` |
| --- | --- |

In my naivety, I tried

```py
def autofunc(basecls: type[A]) -> type[B]:

    @wraps(basecls, updated=())
    class WrappedClass(basecls):

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = basecls(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(instance)

    return WrappedClass
```

which `mypy` really dislikes, raising erros:

- `error: Variable "basecls" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]`
- `error: Invalid base class "basecls"  [misc]`
- also, there is the issue that `WrapperClass.__new__` returns an instance of `B` and not of `WrapperClass`.

Is there any way to properly type hint such a class decorator currently, or is `mypy` not capable to work this yet?

---

Example code:

```py
from functools import wraps


class A:
    pass


class B:
    pass


def func(cl: A) -> B:
    print(f"Replacing {cl=}")
    return B()


def autofunc(basecls: type[A]) -> type[B]:

    @wraps(basecls, updated=())
    class WrappedClass(basecls):

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = basecls()
            return func(instance)

    return WrappedClass
```

Comment: doubt this would fix it, but shouldn't it be `type[A] -> type[A]`?

Comment: @joel I am not sure. The issue is that, the way it is currently written, `WrapperClass` is kind of ill-defined in itself because it subclasses `basecls`, i.e. `type[A]`, but the `__new__`  constructor returns objects of `type[B]`. `MyPy` rightfully complains about this as well, but I haven't found a better alternative yet.

The reason I wrote `type[A] -> type[B]` is that `func` maps `A -> B`. And indeed, technically `autofunc` does  map `type[A] -> type[A]`, but after instantiation you always get `type[B]`.

Comment: yeah good point. On a related note, is it valid to return a `B` from an `A`'s `__new__` if the `B` is not an `A`? I'd have thought that would really break some OO/type assumptions

Comment: @joel It is valid, working python code. But of course it conflicts with the mental model of how classes and `__new__` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a bug in `mypy`: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5865